# In-app purchase iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement in app purchase for iOS 6 and I am following [Ray Wenderlich iOS 6 in-app tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial)  as my reference point. One big change I am making from Ray's code is that I have a single button (there is only 1 in app purchase) that the user taps to purchase opposed to making a custom table view for it. I cannot seem to get it work and I keep getting

```
-[__NSMallocBlock__ allObjects]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d5846d0
2012-10-03 00:03:25.715 myapp[752:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSMallocBlock__ allObjects]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d5846d0'
```

I believe the issue is happening within

```
- (void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler
```

There are 2 helper classes that ray has implemented and I have implemented. All I changed for these was the app id number. These classes are called IAPHelper.h/m and RageIAPHelper.h/m

I have posted the code where I think the error is happening (it is not long). If someone could please help me, I have been working on this for about 4 hours now.
Thank you in advance

**Inside purchaseViewController**

```
 -(void) viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 [self reload]; //Customized for my own needs compared to what Ray had
  }

-(void)reload {
_products = nil;
[[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
    if (success) {
        _products = products;
        //[self.tableView reloadData];
    }
    //[self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
 }];
}
```

**Inside helper method called IAPHelper.m**

```
- (void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler {

// 1
 _completionHandler = [completionHandler copy];
// 2
_productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers]; // This is where I think the crash is
_productsRequest.delegate = self;
[_productsRequest start];
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?

Answer (score 4):

The problem arises if

```
-(void)requestProdcutsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)
    completionHandler{
    ....
{
```

is called twice before the first call completes.  The reason is because the SKProductsRequestDelegate is used and calls the following function when it receives a response:

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:
    (SKProductsResponse *)response{
    ...
    _completionHandler(YES, availableProducts)
    _completionHandler = nil;
}
```

Notice how _completionHandler is set to nil after the response is processed.  Well, when the next response comes through from the duplicate call to "requestProductsWithCompletionHandler", _completionHandler is nil and throws the exception.  You can fix this two ways, either make sure you do not call that function multiple times (bad way) or put some logic to make sure the completionHandler is not in use:

```
-(void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler{

NSLog(@"Request Products");
if (!_completionHandler) {
    NSLog(@"CompletionHandler called, new one was made");
    _completionHandler = [completionHandler copy];

    NSMutableSet * productIdentifiers = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:_products.count];
        for (IAPProduct * product in _products.allValues) {
            product.availableForPurchase = NO;
            [productIdentifiers addObject:product.productIdentifier];
        }

    _productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    _productsRequest.delegate=self;
    [_productsRequest start];
}else{
    NSLog(@"Duplicate call!");
}
}
```

productRequest first checks to make sure _completionHanlder is nil, and if not then it ignores the request since the handler is in use.

Comment: Your code also crashes for me. for me there's a zombie NSSet in _productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers]; Do you know if this tutorial is correct?

Comment: This snippet helped me (thank you ;) ), but not for the same problem than the question. Sometimes, I called twice requestProductsWithCompletionHandler too quickly, resulting in a excbadaccess, not a sigbart unrecognized selector as in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to post an answer rather than a comment for the future readers. I was also following the [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) Tutorial but found a problem in the implementation, that was causing the crash for me.

He declares several two problematic instance variables (for me, at least):

`_productIdentifiers` and `_purchasedProductIdentifiers`
because in the initialization of the singleton he assigns them an object that will be released. Maybe this is because my project is not using ARC but I think not. In any case if you change this code from his tutorial:

```
// Store product identifiers
  /*_productIdentifiers = productIdentifiers; ----> This is the original code */
    _productIdentifiers = [[NSSet alloc]initWithSet:productIdentifiers];  // Replace with this

// Check for previously purchased products
  /*_purchasedProductIdentifiers = [NSMutableSet set]; ----> This is the original code*/
    _purchasedProductsIdentifiers = [[NSMutableSet alloc]init]; //Replace with this
```

Because the other methods release the objects. Or you can declare properties in the declaration and then use the autoreleased version of the objects.

I hope this helps someone, it took me a while to figure it out (Probably because I was just following the tutorial).