# Bad Access Parent is Null - Wht is this Happening?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7

I understand what the error is, but in this case not what is causing it.  In general use it occurs maybe 1% of the time (probably less) but I have found an extreme way to cause it which I will describe below.  First, I am using an in-app purchase process I found on Ray Wenderlich's site.  Below are the specific pieces of concern here:

.h:

```
typedef void (^RequestProductsCompletionHandler)(BOOL success, NSArray * products);
@interface IAPHelper : NSObject

- (void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler;

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation IAPHelper
{
    SKProductsRequest * _productsRequest;
    RequestProductsCompletionHandler _completionHandler;
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

    NSLog(@"Loaded list of products...");
    _productsRequest = nil;

    NSArray * skProducts = response.products;
    for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts) {
        NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
              skProduct.productIdentifier,
              skProduct.localizedTitle,
              skProduct.price.floatValue);
    }

    _completionHandler(YES, skProducts); // here is where bad access occurs 
    _completionHandler = nil;
}
```

Again, 99%+ of the time this works just fine.  Given how infrequent the bad access happens in regular use and it has been difficult to diagnose.  However, I found an extreme way to cause the issue.  The setup is "Tab 1" is a table view controller and "Tab 2" is a table view controller that uses the code from above.  If I quickly switch back and forth between the two tabs I can usually cause the problem to occur anywhere from a few seconds into it to 20-30 seconds.  Doesn't happen every time in this scenario but it does the vast majority.  As marked above the following line gets a bad access error with Parent is Null.

> _completionHandler(YES, skProducts);

To solve the issue I simple do the following:

```
if (_completionHandler)
{
    _completionHandler(YES, skProducts);
    _completionHandler = nil;
}
```

While that fix does work and does solve the problem I am still bothered by why this is occurring.  Any thoughts as to the cause of this?

Update:

Apologies to all as I did forget to include the following in what I pasted above.

```
- (void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler {


    // 1
    _completionHandler = [completionHandler copy];

    // 2
    _productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers];
    _productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [_productsRequest start];

}
```

Comment: Did you copy `completionHandler` when assigning to `_completionHandler `? If not, do it.

Comment: Yes, sorry I neglected to include a method in the OP.  I have updated it above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to treat your completion block as any other object when you are storing it. So if you are storing your block as a variable and then using it within a different scope from where you assign it, you need to increment the reference count by either copying it or retaining it. The simple solution is to create a `strong` property to store your block.

Comment: I am doing the following which I edited into my OP above: _completionHandler = [completionHandler copy];  I forgot to include it in the OP but it is part of the code from the beginning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702909/in-app-purchase-ios-6?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on unseen bits of code, your completion handler block might not be being assigned correctly. You need to copy a block if you intend to use it outside of the scope in which it was created.

In your interface, declare your completion handler's storage attribute as "copy".

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, copy) void (^completionHandler)(BOOL, NSArray *);
```

If you want to control the local variable, you can synthesize the property manually in your implementation:

```
@synthesize completionHandler = _completionHandler;
```

Comment: Please see the copy statement in my edited OP.  I neglected to include this originally in my post.